# Flutter: Check the file before delete it in Firebase Storage

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I have a function that is meant to delete files from Firebase Storage like below:

```
void _deleteFileFromStorage(String fileName) async {
  await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName).delete();
}
```

It's success to delete the File, but when the file to be deleted does not exist in Firebase Storage, it will cause an error and it will stack in the delete function (`_deleteFileFromStorage`), and will not run (pass) to the function / to the next process like this bellow:

```
onPressed: () async {
  await _progressDialog.update(message: 'Deleted Resume...');
  await _progressDialog.show();
  await _deleteFileFromStorage(widget.attachmentsEntity.name); // If the file doesn't exist, the process stuck in here
  await _deleteDataFromFirebase(); // This function and below will not run because it causes an error in the delete function (the file does not exist)
  if (widget.resume.length == 1) {
    setState(() {
      choices.add(Choice(title: RESUME, index: 0));
    });
  }
  await _progressDialog.hide();
  Navigation.back(context);
},
```

So the question is:

1. Can I check the file first before I execute `_deleteFileFromStorage` to delete the file?
2. Or how if the file doesn't exist in Firebase Storage, I just passed the error and continue running the next process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by using `try` and `catch` on the `_deleteFileFromStorage`. So, when the file does not exist (error), it will continue running the next process. If you guys have any option for an answer this question for number 1 or number 2. Just go a head :)

Answer (score 1):

```
try{
String downloadLink = await storage
        .ref('folder/filename.extension')
         .getDownloadURL();
}
catch(error){
print('file not found');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call [getMetadata()](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/StorageReference/getMetadata.html) on the Reference.  If it finishes and returns a metadata object, then the file exists.  If it yields an error, then you can assume that the file doesn't exist, or that the client doesn't have permission to delete it.

Personally, I would just log the error from `delete()` and move on.

Comment: The link is now 404'd - updated link: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#adding-metadata

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
var file = storageRef
      .child('fileName');

      if(file != null){
          storageRef
      .child('fileName').delete();
      }else{
       print('Does not exist');
      }
```

Comment: This will not work.  It's just checking if the reference object is not null.  This does not mean the file exists in Cloud Storage.

Comment: how would the file name be in the storage and it would not exist..

Comment: You can build a reference to a file that doesn't exist.  That actually how you perform an upload.  The reference object is just a path, not an actual file.