# The method 'exists' isn't defined for the type 'Reference'

Tags: flutter, dart

When I try to delete a file (already previously deleted) in my database, it says the following: "The method 'exists' isn't defined for the type 'Reference'. "

I think it is because when I send to call the path it does not find any file and that is why it mentions me that it does not exist.

The method 'exists' isn't defined for the type 'Reference'.

Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'exists'

```
    String ref = _selectedRef!;

    if (!ref.startsWith("/")) {

      ref = "/" + ref;

    }

    ref = ref.substring(0, ref.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) + ".pdf";
```

There is my problem:

```
    // validate if the reference exists

    **bool exists = await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(ref).exists();**
```

And here we need to wait if exists the reference:

```
if (exists) {

      await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(ref).delete();

      await FirebaseFirestore.instance

          .collection("file")

          .where("ref", isEqualTo: _selectedRef)

          .get()

          .then((snapshot) {

        snapshot.docs.first.reference.delete();

      });

      setState(() {

        _selectedRef = null;

      });

    } else {

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(

          SnackBar(content: Text("El archivo seleccionado no existe")));

    }

  }
```

This is my full code:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'dart:math';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

import 'package:fimprac/screen_acercade.dart';

import 'package:fimprac/screen_home.dart';

import 'package:fimprac/main.dart';

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter/src/material/navigation_drawer.dart';

import 'package:fimprac/menu.dart';

import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer/pdfviewer.dart';

main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(MaterialApp(

    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

    home: perfilSC(),

  ));

}

class perfilSC extends StatefulWidget {

  const perfilSC({super.key});

  @override

  State<perfilSC> createState() => _perfilSCState();

}

class _perfilSCState extends State<perfilSC> {

  String?

      _selectedRef; //agrega una variable para almacenar la referencia del archivo seleccionado

  String url = "";

  int? number;

  late QueryDocumentSnapshot selectedSnapshot;

  uploadDataToFirebase() async {

    //generate random number

    number = Random().nextInt(10);

    //pick pdf file

    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

    File pick = File(result!.files.single.path.toString());

    var file = pick.readAsBytesSync();

    String name = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

    //uploading file to firebase

    var pdfFile = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(name).child("/.pdf");

    UploadTask task = pdfFile.putData(file);

    TaskSnapshot snapshot = await task;

    url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

    String ref = name + "/.pdf"; // establece la referencia del archivo

    //upload to url to cloud firebase

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("file").doc().set({

      'fileUrl': url,

      'num': "CV#" + number.toString(),

      'ref': name + "/.pdf" // agrega la referencia del archivo

    });

  }

  Future<void> deleteFile() async {

    if (_selectedRef != null) {

      showDialog(

        context: context,

        builder: (BuildContext context) {

          return AlertDialog(

            title: Text('¿Estás seguro que quieres eliminar el archivo?'),

            actions: <Widget>[

              TextButton(

                child: Text('Cancelar'),

                onPressed: () {

                  Navigator.of(context).pop();

                },

              ),

              TextButton(

                child: Text('Eliminar'),

                onPressed: () async {

                  await deleteFirebaseData();

                  Navigator.of(context).pop();

                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(

                      SnackBar(content: Text("Archivo eliminado")));

                },

              ),

            ],

          );

        },

      );

    } else {

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(

          SnackBar(content: Text("Selecciona un archivo para eliminar")));

    }

  }

  Future<void> deleteFirebaseData() async {

    if (_selectedRef == null) {

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(

          SnackBar(content: Text("Selecciona un archivo para eliminar")));

      return;

    }

    // construir la ruta completa de la referencia del archivo

    String ref = _selectedRef!;

    if (!ref.startsWith("/")) {

      ref = "/" + ref;

    }

    ref = ref.substring(0, ref.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) + ".pdf";

    // validar si la referencia existe

    bool exists = await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(ref).exists();

    if (exists) {

      await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(ref).delete();

      await FirebaseFirestore.instance

          .collection("file")

          .where("ref", isEqualTo: _selectedRef)

          .get()

          .then((snapshot) {

        snapshot.docs.first.reference.delete();

      });

      setState(() {

        _selectedRef = null;

      });

    } else {

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(

          SnackBar(content: Text("El archivo seleccionado no existe")));

    }

  }

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(

      drawer: const NavigationDrawerMenu(),

      appBar: AppBar(

        backgroundColor: Colors.green,

        title: Text('PDF'),

      ),

      body: StreamBuilder(

          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("file").snapshots(),

          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

            if (snapshot.hasData) {

              return ListView.builder(

                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,

                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {

                    QueryDocumentSnapshot x = snapshot.data!.docs[i];

                    return InkWell(

                      onTap: () {

                        setState(() {

                          selectedSnapshot = x; // asignar valor a la variable

                        });

                        Navigator.push(

                            context,

                            MaterialPageRoute(

                                builder: (context) => View(

                                      url: x['fileUrl'],

                                    )));

                      },

                      child: Container(

                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),

                        child: Text(x["num"]),

                      ),

                    );

                  });

            }

            return Center(

              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),

            );

          }),

      floatingActionButton: Row(

        children: [

          FloatingActionButton(

            heroTag: "btn1",

            onPressed: () {

              setState(() {

                _selectedRef = selectedSnapshot[

                    'ref']; //almacena la referencia del archivo seleccionado

              });

              deleteFile();

            },

            child: Icon(Icons.delete),

          ),

          SizedBox(width: 10),

          Expanded(

            child: FloatingActionButton(

              heroTag: "btn2",

              onPressed: () => uploadDataToFirebase(),

              child: Icon(Icons.add),

            ),

          ),

        ],

      ),

    );

  }

}

class View extends StatelessWidget {

  PdfViewerController? _pdfViewerController;

  final url;

  View({this.url});

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text("PDF VIEW"),

      ),

      body: SfPdfViewer.network(

        url,

        controller: _pdfViewerController,

      ),

    );

  }

}
```

Comment: you forgot to ask a question ... also, it is not clear what the problem is ... you described what happens, but you did not say what you expected to happen

Comment: When I try to delete a file (already previously deleted) in my database, it says the following: "The method 'exists' isn't defined for the type 'Reference'. "

I think it is because when I send to call the path it does not find any file and that is why it mentions me that it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, there is no `.exists` method for cloud storage. That is a method used to check files on device local storage.

Follow this document to check for files existing on cloud storage... https://jsmobiledev.com/article/storage-file-exist/ it's for JavaScript but the principal is the same.
Also this SO answer  [Flutter: Check the file before delete it in Firebase Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62234982/flutter-check-the-file-before-delete-it-in-firebase-storage)

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so, please mark it as accepted and/or upvote it. That is what keeps SO going.